# how to show Date from DatePicker on click of EditText and set selected date on it. EditText is in every listView item in array Adapter

Tags: android, listview, datepicker, android-arrayadapter

I have customized listView using ArrayAdapter. In ArrayAdapter i have EditText which should pop up Datepicker. On date set i want that date to set on perticular row of listView. Here is my code

CustomReminder.java

```
    public class CustomSetRem extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {

    Context context;
    List< String> people= new ArrayList<String>();
    SqlManager db;
    String remDate;

    public CustomSetRem(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row2, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context= context;
        this.people=objects;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name,date;
        protected static EditText postDate;
        protected Switch rem;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.remDate=date;
        System.out.println("date: "+remDate);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        db=new SqlManager(getContext());

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerName);
            viewHolder.date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NextCall);
            viewHolder.postDate= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postponedDate);
            viewHolder.rem= (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RemOff);

            viewHolder.rem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), " Not checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.customerName,viewHolder.name);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.NextCall, viewHolder.date);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.postponedDate,viewHolder.postDate);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.RemOff,viewHolder.rem);
        }
        else 
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.name.setText(people.get(position));
        viewHolder.date.setText(db.getNextCall(people.get(position)));
        viewHolder.rem.setTag(position);
        System.out.println("postdate: "+remDate);
        viewHolder.postDate.setText(remDate);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    }


row2.xml

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="Contact Name"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NextCall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Next Call Date"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/RemOff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:checked="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/postponedDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:hint="Postpone Date"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:onClick="setDate" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

SetReminder.java

    public  void setDate(View v)
        {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(v);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
        }

        public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnDateSetListener
        {
        View v;

        public DatePickerFragment(View v2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            v = v2;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v.getId() == R.id.postponedDate) 
            {       

                String date= String.valueOf(arg3)+"-"+String.valueOf(++arg2)+"-"+String.valueOf(arg1);
                adapter.setDate(date);
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            }

        }

    }
```

Problem is I am not understanding where to set date on EditText. It shows date picker onClick of EditText . But does not set value on it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. The list does not refreshes
2. Adapter can only save one value of remDate

To fix both, I would try passing the EditText to DatePickerFragment and set its value inside the event onDateSet. I guess that way you would not need to refresh the whole list and could remove remDate field and setDate method on adapter

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it. That method will set the Date on last EditText of List. But not on clicked one.

Comment: How are you showing the DatePicker? on the click event inside EditText?

Comment: Ya. On clicking of editText date picker will pop out

Comment: I guess you're calling setDate(View v) but which view are you passing? Did you tried to pass the EditText?